# Can you override phoenix templates partials with block supers (like Django?)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

What is the recommended way to differentiate a HTML block in phoenix templating?

I've read the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/live-layouts.html); which draws the following outlines;

- the root layout is injected by a plug in the router
- you can optionally set a layout on a route
- you can optionally set a layout on a view

But is it possible (or otherwise recommended) to override just a template block somehow? For example Django let's you do things like;

**base_template**

```
{% block header %}
  <%= render "_header.html", assigns %>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  stuff..
{% endblock %}
```

**inheriting_view_template**

```
{% extends "base_template.html" %}

{% block header %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <p>my super interesting extra header context</p> <-- !
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  stuff..
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: answered on elixirforum; https://elixirforum.com/t/can-you-override-phoenix-templates-partials-with-block-supers-like-django/36992

Answer (score 1):

So it is something similar to Rails world

`some_layout.erb`

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
      <%= yield :header %>
    </header>
    <div>
      <%= yield :content %>
    </div>
    <footer>
       <%= yield :footer %>
    </footer>
  </body>
<html>
```

And just to generalise your answer (for further readers). Two methods possible

[`render_existing`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render_existing/3) Renders a template only if it exists.

```html
<head>
  <%= render_existing view_module(@conn), "scripts.html", assigns %>
</head>
```

[`render_layout`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render_layout/4) Renders the given layout passing the given do/end block as `@inner_content`.

```html
# layout/blog.html.eex
<%= render_layout LayoutView, "app.html", assigns do %>
  <div class="sidebar">...</div>
  <%= @inner_content %>
<% end %>
```